# Optimizing a table - Twig, CSS

Tags: php, css, twig

I have a table with forms in two colors - the first row is one color, the second is the other. Can you please tell me if there is a way to optimize my code (such as with [this](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_table_layout.html.twig))?

I have two CSS classes:

```
tr.content1{  
    background-color: #EFF4FA; 
}

tr.content2{  
    background-color: #F7FAFD; 
}
```

And the table looks this way:

```
    <tr class="content1">
        <td>Previous Plan:</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.prev_plan) }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="content2">
        <td>Previous Server:</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form.prev_srv) }}</td>
    </tr>
```

There is also a problem this way - I get some text in the second column in front of the form field.

Comment: ewww... Tables and CSS together, what blasphemy!

Comment: @showerhead: Well, how else would one structure and style tabular data?

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: You can use spans and divs in this case, but there are other solutions too.

Comment: @showerhead: That is far less semantic than using tables, and far less accessible to users of assistive technologies. `DL`s _maybe_. But tables are still the ideal and most proper way of presenting tabular data.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: I admit to not being well versed in this topic, which probably disqualifies me from this discussion already, but spans and divs are standards and are still presented sequentially, so they should still be accessible by assistive technologies. They are cleaner, which makes them ideal for developers, and can be stylized with CSS far more easier.

Comment: @showerhead: There is nothing "clean" about having a document entirely comprised of `div`s and `span`s and using CSS to imitate the proper semantic elements. That'd be like replacing all of your links with `spans` that have `onclick` handlers or using `span`s in place of `h1`, `h2`, `h3`.... `div`s and `span`s do not have a `summary` attribute, `colgroup`s, proper table headers, nor do they have `axis`, `scope`, or `headers` attributes to associate the data cells with their respective headers.

Comment: And if all we should be using are `div`s and `span`s just because they can be styled using CSS to look however you want, then why bother having so many semantically specific tags in HTML? Why bother having `h1`-`h6`/`p`/`blockquote`/`table`/`thead`/`tbody`/`tr`/`th`/`td`/`ul`/`section`/`nav`/etc.? Or better yet, why not just use only `div`s or only `span`s? After all, you can set either of them to render as block-level or inline elements.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté: I believe we have come to misunderstand one another. I may have been too general in my first comment and I did not clear it up in any of the following ones. My Apologies. Hopefully this clears it up a little better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Comment: Never would it be acceptable to replace prefab elements with stylized "replacements". And if the OP were using all of the properties you mentioned, or even just some, I would not have said anything. However this is a VERY simplistic LAYOUT. It is not tabular, except for the fact that it has a header. My comment was to imply that you can get a similar layout more simply and cleanly with div and spans and that a table in this instance was unnecessary. You can just as easily use section, H1, and p tags to accomplish the same thing, it need not be entirely divs and spans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your requirements (is javascript allowed, which browsers can be used), I'd go for a CSS only solution.

**CSS:**

```
table.zebra tr:nth-child(odd) {  
    background-color: #EFF4FA; 
}

table.zebra tr:nth-child(even) {  
    background-color: #F7FAFD; 
}
```

**PHP:**

```
<table class="zebra">
  <tr>
    <td>Previous Plan:</td>
    <td>{{ form_row(form.prev_plan) }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Previous Server:</td>
    <td>{{ form_row(form.prev_srv) }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's the catch:

You can't use these wonderfull selectors in every browser (IE < 9, I'm looking at you!). Only in most of them. There's a great explanation of the [selector at w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo) and an overview over browsers supporting it at [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

And if you still want to use CSS3 selectors and need early IE support, there's javascript providing it (e.g. [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) - I never used it, but it's easy to find alternatives). Just search for "css3 selectors in IE" in your favorite search engine.

I guess this still doesn't solve your text overlay issues, but for that, you'd best point to an example page.